# MySQL Insert Into table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact_forms(name,ts,ip,email,option,msg)
        VALUES('".$name."', 
        NOW(),
        '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', 
        '".$email."', 
        '".$option."', 
        '".$message."')");
```

For some reason this thing doesn't work. It throws no errors but it just doesn't work. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: `echo mysql_error();` right after this. And remember, to get help - always post here **plain sql**, without any php.

Comment: post the table structure

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are doing this in PHP, which is what it appears to be, try changing your code to this to see if you get an error that might be able to add a little more information:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact_forms(name,ts,ip,email,option,msg)
        VALUES('".$name."', 
        NOW(),
        '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', 
        '".$email."', 
        '".$option."', 
        '".$message."')", $link);

echo mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . "<br>";
```

In this example the variable `$link` is your database connection string.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php for more information on usage.

Comment: Well I thank you for your help, here is the error I seem to be getting... 

Warning: mysql_errno() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Comment: I think that error may actually be referring to `$link` being null. 

However, if you have the `$link` variable set as I mentioned earlier, then it may be that one of the variables in your SQL statement is null and not set.  You may want to try to `echo` your variable to make sure they are all being set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Put mysql_error() as zerkms suggested.

**Update**

option is a MySQL [link=http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html]reserved word[/link] and you can not use it unless you enclose it with back tick (`).

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact_forms(name,ts,ip,email,`option`,msg)
    VALUES('".$name."', 
    NOW(),
    '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', 
    '".$email."', 
    '".$option."', 
    '".$message."')");
```

Always use mysql_error() to debug query issues. It is not a good practice to use reserve words in database schema.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option,msg) VALUES('Andrew', NOW(), '192.168.1.115',' at line 1
code is exactly the same as my post...

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
   $date = now();
   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   $query = "INSERT INTO contact_forms (name,ts,ip,email,option,msg)
          VALUES('$name',
          '$date',
          '$ip',
          '$email',
          '$option',
          '$message')";
```

Comment: You changed nothing. Moreover this code will work not like the code in the question, due to removed `NOW()`